# C# - Using regular Console.WriteLine formatting in a custom console extension method?

Tags: c#, console

I'm currently writing a small console game and I created a custom class, Xconsole, with a method to display the text in a specific area of the console as well as give a "scrolling effect" to the  game messages.

```
public static int CurrentConsoleLine = 46;
public static List<String> XconsoleBuffer = new List<String>();

public static void MessageToConsole(string message)
{
    if (CurrentConsoleLine >= 59)
    {
        XconsoleBuffer.RemoveAt(12);
        XconsoleBuffer.Insert(0, message);
        ClearMessageBox();

        for (int i = 0; i < XconsoleBuffer.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, (46 + i));
            Console.WriteLine(XconsoleBuffer[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, CurrentConsoleLine);
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        XconsoleBuffer.Add(message);
        CurrentConsoleLine++;
    }
}
```

However, since the text to be written is passed as an argument in the function, I noticed that I cannot use the formatting option Console.WriteLine usually provide and while this does work :

```
Xconsole.MessageToConsole(Name + " hits the " + monster.Name + " for " + damage + " damage. " + monster.Name + " now has " + monster.CurrentHp + " hp remaining.");
```

I'd rather prefer to write this so that the string is easier to read

```
Xconsole.MessageToConsole("{0} hits the {1} for {2} damage. {1} now has {3} hp remaining", Name, monster.Name, damage, monster.CurrentHp);
```

Is there any way I can modify the MessageToConsole method to be able to either replace the Console.WriteLine or use the formatting option with the call to WriteLine already there?

Thanks in advance for your answer, I hope that this time I didn't put too much information.

Also, I know that the code is kind of hack-ish right now so if you got an idea to replace the whole thing, feel free to share. I'm still learning so comment are appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't `public void MessageToConsole(string format, params object[] args) { ... Console.WriteLine(format, args); ... }` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple use string interpolation that was broad with c#6

```
Xconsole.MessageToConsole($"{Name} hits the {monster.Name} for {damage} damage. {monster.Name} now has {monster.CurrentHp} hp remaining");
```

Just put a dollar symbol before your string and use the variable names in the brackets.

You can read more about string interpolation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot!  This is awesome and it's even better than having a bunch of {#} in the middle of the string.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply overload your function with a variable for the arguments using the [**`params`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) keyword:

```
public static void MessageToConsole(string format, params object[] args) 
{
    MessageToConsole(String.Format(format, args));
}
```

This will then allow you to invoke the method with parameters as you would with [`String.Format(format, args[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Xconsole.MessageToConsole("{0} hits the {1} for {2} damage. {1} now has {3} hp remaining", Name, monster.Name, damage, monster.CurrentHp);
```

Comment: beside my solution this is the more oop approach and c# version <6 compatible solution. For c version >= 6 my solution saves you lot of coding time.

Comment: @MartinGodzina your solution works also, but do you really consider writing a one-line overload to be "a lot of coding time"?

Comment: in my opinion its unnecessary boiler plate code (i count 4 lines by the way) but there is no right solution if you´r using c# version >= 6. So this more a code design debate. And you need more code to call the method. :)